# Reverse an array, but doesn't work

Tags: java, arrays

I know this is pretty basic, but I don't know why my code doesn't work. The code below is supposed to reverse the array, but I'm seriously dying to know why the output stays the same! Any explanation will be appreciated :)

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] oldList = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        reverse(oldList);
        for (int i = 0; i < oldList.length; i++)
            System.out.print(oldList[i] + " ");
    }
    public static void reverse(int[] list) {
        int[] newList = new int[list.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
            newList[newList.length] = list[list.length - 1 - i];
        list = newList;
    }
}
```

Comment: `list = newList` does not change the array in your `main` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to modify the method according to the following:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] oldList = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        oldList = reverse(oldList); //assign the returned value from the method
        for (int i = 0; i < oldList.length; i++)
            System.out.print(oldList[i] + " ");
    }
    public static int[] reverse(int[] list) {
        int[] newList = new int[list.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
            newList[newList.length] = list[list.length - 1 - i];
        list = newList;
        return list;
    }
}
```

To find more details about this read more about **pass by value and pass by reference** in Java.

Comment: Can you explain why omitting void solve the problem? What's the problem with void? I thought the list array is static, so it should work?

Comment: @PemiNg `void` in front of a method means it won't return anything. But you will have to return the `int[]`.

Comment: Thanks! now I get it!

Comment: @PemiNg If it helped can you please accept the answer?

Comment: Already did! Thanks a lot